# Quick and efficient filtering of a listbox bound to a collection in the ViewModel

Tags: linq, mvvm, filtering

On my wpf window I have two listboxes. One is for the available items and the other is for the selected items. The available items will usually hold 3000+ items when not filtered. The user is presented with a combobox to filter the item type and a textbox to filter the item name. Currently I'm using Linq to filter the items, but it is refreshing the list very slowly. I'm wondering if there is a better approach.

Some notes of interest: I've created an attached behavior to allow me to bind the selecteditems (note the 's') property to the viewmodel and this behavior requires a collection type in order to work.
I have the text filter set to update the property when changed and in the property setter I call the filter method.

View:

```
<DatePicker Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Height="26" VerticalAlignment="Center" SelectedDate="{Binding FromDate}" />
<DatePicker Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Height="26" VerticalAlignment="Center" SelectedDate="{Binding ToDate}" />
<ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding Classes}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedClass}" />
<TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding CiNameFilterText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="55,0,0,178" />
<ListBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Height="172" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableCis}" DisplayMemberPath="CiName" SelectionMode="Extended" Ocean_WPF:ListBoxBehavior.SelectedItems="{Binding AvailableCisSelected}" Margin="0,28,0,0" />
<ListBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Height="200" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedCis}" DisplayMemberPath="CiName" SelectionMode="Extended" Ocean_WPF:ListBoxBehavior.SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedCisSelected}" />
```

ViewModel:

```
Protected Sub FilterCiList()
    Try
        If (_caCiData IsNot Nothing) Then
            If ((_selectedClass IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not _selectedClass.Equals(String.Empty)) AndAlso (_ciNameFilterText IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not _ciNameFilterText.Equals(String.Empty))) Then
                Me.AvailableCis = New ObservableCollection(Of CA.SoftwareRow)(_caCiData.Where(Function(ci) ci.Class.ToUpper.Equals(_selectedClass.ToUpper) AndAlso ci.CiName.ToUpper.Contains(_ciNameFilterText.ToUpper)).OrderBy(Function(a) a.CiName))
            ElseIf ((_selectedClass IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not _selectedClass.Equals(String.Empty)) AndAlso (_ciNameFilterText Is Nothing OrElse _ciNameFilterText.Equals(String.Empty))) Then
                Me.AvailableCis = New ObservableCollection(Of CA.SoftwareRow)(_caCiData.Where(Function(ci) ci.Class.ToUpper.Equals(_selectedClass.ToUpper)).OrderBy(Function(a) a.CiName))
            ElseIf ((_selectedClass Is Nothing OrElse _selectedClass.Equals(String.Empty)) AndAlso (_ciNameFilterText IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not _ciNameFilterText.Equals(String.Empty))) Then
                Me.AvailableCis = New ObservableCollection(Of CA.SoftwareRow)(_caCiData.Where(Function(ci) ci.CiName.ToUpper.Contains(_ciNameFilterText.ToUpper)).OrderBy(Function(a) a.CiName))
            Else
                Me.AvailableCis = New ObservableCollection(Of CA.SoftwareRow)(_caCiData.OrderBy(Function(a) a.CiName))
            End If

            If (Me.SelectedCis IsNot Nothing) Then
                For Each Ci In Me.SelectedCis
                    Me.AvailableCis.Remove(Ci)
                Next
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        _viewModelUIService.ExceptionDialog(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

_caCiData is the full unfiltered list. If I filter the list I need to display only the items that match the filter so I am simply adding those items to the AvailableCis Property using a Linq query.

There must be a better way to do this as the filtering is slow (takes about 5 seconds before it's able to refresh the list in the view)

Edit: a friend of mine suggested a dataview, would that work better than filtering the whole collection each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured this one out. The same friend who suggested the Dataview just remembered that there is a bug with WPF and loading it with too many items. This really slowed the UI down. I changed the listboxes to Datagrids and styled them to look like listboxes. The result was night and day. I have the speed I want now.